# How to terminate the nested loop

Tags: c, embedded, atmel, 8051

Here I want to break out of a nested loop. I am using `break` statements to do so. The code is breaking out of the `for` loops but can't get out of the infinite `while` loop. I want to go to another function called `resetClock()` when the condition is true. I have tried every possible solution `return`, `goto` and `break` and still I am facing the same problem.

```
 #define MUX_PORT  P3
 #define enable_int{EA=1;}
 #define disable_int{EA=0;}

 void timer0() interrupt 1 {
     TL0 = 0x33;
     TH0 = 0xF5;
     MUX_PORT = 0x00;
     dig1 = dig2 = dig3 = dig4 = 0;
     DATA_PORT = 0x00;
     if (dig_disp > 4)
         dig_disp = 0;
     dig_disp++;

     switch (dig_disp) {
     case 1:
         dig1 = 1;
         MUX_PORT = seg_hex[sec0];
         break;
     case 2:
         dig2 = 1;
         MUX_PORT = seg_hex[sec1];
         break;
     case 3:
         dig3 = 1;
         MUX_PORT = seg_hex[min0];
         break;
     case 4:
         dig4 = 1;
         MUX_PORT = seg_hex[min1];
         break;
     }
 }

 void msDelay() {
     unsigned int i;
     for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
         TMOD = 0x10;
         TH1 = 0x4B;
         TL1 = 0xFD;
         TR1 = 1;
         while (TF1 == 0);
         TR1 = 0;
         TF1 = 0;
     }
 }

 void start_Clock() {
     unsigned int loop_break = 0;
     TMOD = 0x01;
     TH0 = 0xF5;
     TL0 = 0x33; //63293
     IE = 0x82;
     TR0 = 1;
     while (SW_SHIFT == 1) {
         for (min1 = 0; min1 < 6; min1++) {
             for (min0 = 0; min0 <= 9; min0++) {
                 for (sec1 = 0; sec1 < 6; sec1++) {
                     for (sec0 = 0; sec0 <= 9; sec0++) {
                         msDelay();
                         if (SW_SHIFT == 0) {
                             loop_break = 1;
                             disable_int;
                             MUX_PORT = 0xFF;
                             dig1 = dig2 = dig3 = dig4 = 0;
                             break;
                         }
                         if (min0 == 2 && min1 == 1) {
                             min0 = 1;
                             min1 = 0;
                             sec0 = 0;
                             sec1 = 0;
                             continue;
                         }
                     }
                     if (loop_break == 1) break;
                 }
                 if (loop_break == 1) break;
             }
             if (loop_break == 1) break;
         }
         if (loop_break == 1) {
             resetClock();
         }
     }
 }

 void main() {
     unsigned int i, j;
     sec0 = sec1 = min0 = min1 = 0;

     SW_SET = 1;
     SW_SHIFT = 1;

     for (i = 0; i <= 250; i++)
         for (j = 0; j <= 1257; j++);

     start_Clock();
 }

 void resetClock() {
     unsigned int i, j, k, l;
     i = j = k = l = 0;
     SW_SHIFT = 1;
     SW_SET = 1;

     if (SW_SHIFT == 0) {
         dig_disp++;
         if (dig_disp > 3)
             dig_disp = 0;
     }
     switch (dig_disp) {
     case 0:
         while (SW_SET == 0) {
             dig1 = 1;
             i++;
             sec0 = i;
             MUX_PORT = seg_hex[sec0];
             if (i == 9)
                 i = 0;
         }
         break;

     case 1:
         while (SW_SET == 0) {
             dig2 = 1;
             j++;
             sec1 = j;
             MUX_PORT = seg_hex[sec1];
             if (j == 5)
                 j = 0;
         }
         break;

     case 2:
         while (SW_SET == 0) {
             dig3 = 1;
             k++;
             min0 = k;
             MUX_PORT = seg_hex[min0];
             if (k == 9)
                 k = 0;
         }
         break;

     case 3:
         while (SW_SET == 0) {
             dig4 = 1;
             l++;
             min1 = l;
             MUX_PORT = seg_hex[min1];
             if (l == 1)
                 l = 0;
         }
         break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: The `if(dig_disp>4)` probably acts differently than you expect. It only affects the first following statement.

Comment: In general you should try to avoid nesting more than 3 levels deep.  If you are, need to re-think the way you are solving your problem.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Theproblem is not with dig_disp its working fine for if(dig_disp>3) also and this condition is in interrupt function and i'm disabling the interrupt before proceeding further. The problem is within the while(1) loop.

Comment: You might post another question explaining what this code needs to do and asking for a simpler solution.  You appear to be making a simple thing over-complicated, and are then asking a question about a problem caused by that complexity.  You are making no attempt to exit the outer while loop, why are you surprised?

Comment: @Clifford I have tried every possible solution. I have even used goto break and return to solve this problem. There may be some typo error in my code but i had put the break statement outside the while loop.

Comment: @4386427 SW_SHIFT is a switch used to toggle between the 7 segment display and SW_SET is a switch used to increment the digits of seven segment

Comment: You misunderstand; the code given will not exit the loop because the exit condition is never met and there is no break in the outer loop.  Either break after the `resetClock()` call or replace the `resetClock()` call with a break and call `resetClock()` outside the loop.  That;s the quick fix, but it is a horrible design.  `break`, `goto`, and `continue` are all best avoided, and any perceived need to use them often suggests a poor design in general.  The question is better answered by using a debugger; you have dumped a lot of code for a very simple question.

Comment: It is no good just telling us what you tried; you have to show us - because we cannot see what you tried and how you got it wrong otherwise.  In the code as it stands, you have made no attempt to code an exit from the loop, so what are you asking?  You would do well also to remove the extraneous code unrelated to the question - it is bad enough to attract comments unrelated to your question, and is therefore a distraction.  It will almost certainly fail if you apply compiler optimisation for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to write the code, in what I believe is the most readable way, would be to use functions and returns:

```
void start_Clock() {
     unsigned int loop_break = 0;
     TMOD = 0x01;
     TH0 = 0xF5;
     TL0 = 0x33; //63293
     IE = 0x82;
     TR0 = 1;

     delay(); // give this some meaningful function name

     resetClock();
 }

void delay (void)
{
  while (SW_SHIFT == 1) {
    for (min1 = 0; min1 < 6; min1++) {
      for (min0 = 0; min0 <= 9; min0++) {
        for (sec1 = 0; sec1 < 6; sec1++) {
          for (sec0 = 0; sec0 <= 9; sec0++) {
            msDelay();

            if (SW_SHIFT == 0) {
              disable_int; // NOTE: this looks fishy, likely bug
              MUX_PORT = 0xFF;
              dig1 = dig2 = dig3 = dig4 = 0;
              return ;
            }

            if (min0 == 2 && min1 == 1) {
              min0 = 1;
              min1 = 0;
              sec0 = 0;
              sec1 = 0;
            }

          } // for (sec0 = 0; sec0 <= 9; sec0++)
        } // for (sec1 = 0; sec1 < 6; sec1++)
      } // for (min0 = 0; min0 <= 9; min0++)
    } // for (min1 = 0; min1 < 6; min1++) 
  } // while (SW_SHIFT == 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `while` condition, try adding another check which remains `true` as long as you want to continue in the nested `for` loops. Ensure that this check becomes `false` whenever you set the condition to break out of the `for` loops.

```
while((SW_SHIFT==1) && (cond_to_break_while == false)) {
for1() {
    for2() {
         ....
         forN() {
             cond_to_break_all_the_forloops = true;
             cond_to_break_while = true;
         }
         ....
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Wow - if that is the answer, I really did not understand the question! The question does not suggest that the need to exit the while loop is independent of the need to exit the for loops.

Answer (score 1):

There are not many good usages of `goto` but breaking out of nested loops is one of them.

Try something like this:

```
while (SW_SHIFT == 1) {
    for (min1 = 0; min1 < 6; min1++) {
        for (min0 = 0; min0 <= 9; min0++) {
            for (sec1 = 0; sec1 < 6; sec1++) {
                for (sec0 = 0; sec0 <= 9; sec0++) {
                    msDelay();
                    if (SW_SHIFT == 0) {
                        disable_int;
                        MUX_PORT = 0xFF;
                        dig1 = dig2 = dig3 = dig4 = 0;
                        goto myLabel;
                    }
                    if (min0 == 2 && min1 == 1) {
                        min0 = 1;
                        min1 = 0;
                        sec0 = 0;
                        sec1 = 0;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

myLabel:
    resetClock();
```

Of course, you could instead just add that condition to the while condition like: `while (SW_SHIFT == 1 && loop_break == 0)` but in my opinion it looks much cleaner with a `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

Just set all counters to their end-value and you are done:

```
while (SW_SHIFT == 1) {
     for (min1 = 0; min1 < 6; min1++) {
         for (min0 = 0; min0 <= 9; min0++) {
             for (sec1 = 0; sec1 < 6; sec1++) {
                 for (sec0 = 0; sec0 <= 9; sec0++) {
                     msDelay();
                     if (SW_SHIFT == 0) {
                         min1 = 6;
                         min0 = 9+1;
                         sec1 = 6;
                         sec0 = 9+1;
                     }
                     else if (min0 == 2 && min1 == 1) {
                         min1 = 0;
                         min0 = 1;
                         sec1 = 0;
                         sec0 = 0;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

No `break` needed if using an `else` around the rest of the inner loop.

The `continue` statement as per your code is redundant.

Also using "*magic numbers*" like `9` and `6` is considered bad practise. Consider using `const`s, `enum`s or `#define`s instead.